# Sorting string into identical words

Tags: python, string, sorting

```
word = "help"
scrambled = ['p','e','h','l']
```

how would I arranged scrambled to be the same order as word? so pehl into help.

edit 1:

```
this is for a hangman game, so it would go:
guess 1:
input = "p"
scrambled = ['p']
guess 2:
input = "e"
scrambled = ['p','e']
```

and so on.

Comment: I don’t understand that question as you just could split `word` into a character list.

Comment: Do you only have `scrambled` to start with? Why can't you just use `list(word)`? Do you need to rearrange the letters to come up with various new words? Your problem isn't defined well enough to understand.

Comment: Do you also have cases like `word = "helpl"; scrambled = ['p','e','l','h','l']` ?
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(word)` would do it the quickest..

but to sort `scrambled` you could use:

```
sorted(scrambled, key=word.index)
```

or, using in-place sorting:

```
scrambled.sort(key=word.index)
```

This works *only* when `word` has no repeated letters. For each entry in `scrambled`, `word.index()` is called, returning the index of each letter in `word`, which then are used to sort the `scrambled` list.

Demo:

```
>>> word = "help"
>>> scrambled = ['p','e','h','l']
>>> list(word)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'p']
>>> sorted(scrambled, key=word.index)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'p']
```

For repeated letters, you can build a key function based on the `word` indices:

```
def make_sort_key(word):
    indices = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        indices.setdefault(c, []).append(i)
    def key(c):
        return indices[c].pop()
    return key

sorted(scrambled, key=make_sort_key(word))
```

This pre-builds indices for each letter in `word` and returns these as the `scrambled` list is sorted.

Demo:

```
>>> word = 'letters'
>>> scrambled = ['s', 'e', 'l', 'r', 'e', 't', 't']
>>> def make_sort_key(word):
...     indices = {}
...     for i, c in enumerate(word):
...         indices.setdefault(c, []).append(i)
...     def key(c):
...         return indices[c].pop()
...     return key
... 
>>> sorted(scrambled, key=make_sort_key(word))
['l', 'e', 't', 't', 'e', 'r', 's']
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit how this works Martijn?

Comment: That's a nice use of the sorting key. Pity it would take more work to make it work on words with repeated letters.

Comment: This would work, but what would I do if I got a word with repeated letters? like letters for example.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: I added a key factory that'll work for words with repeated letters.

Comment: I think the key factory is the one I want thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted this literally:

```
>>> word = "help"
>>> scrambled = ['p','e','h','l', 'p','e','h','l', ]
>>> scrambled.sort(key=word.find)
>>> scrambled
['h', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'p', 'p']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with repeated letters:

```
def make_key(word):
    prev = {}
    def key(c):
        prev[c] = word.index(c, prev.get(c, -1) + 1)
        return prev[c]
    return key
```

For example:

```
>>> word = 'lollipop'
>>> scrambled = ['o', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'p', 'p', 'o', 'l']
>>> scrambled.sort(key=make_key(word))
>>> scrambled
['l', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'i', 'p', 'o', 'p']
```